# C while loop partially performs one extra iteration

Tags: c, while-loop

So after running the following code, on first iteration it prints out the menu variable and waits for a couple of inputs. But when it gets to the second iteration it just skips gets() and switch() only printing menu and blank "input" var. But then on the third iteration it performs appropriate. 
So why does it skip every second iteration in such way?

```
int main(void) {
    char menu[] = "1 - run first task\n2 - run se...";
    while (1) {
        char input[20];
        printf(menu);
        gets(input);
        puts(input);
        if (checker1(input))
            switch(input[0]) {
            case ('1'):
                task1();
                break;
            case('2'):
                task2();
                break;
            case('c'):
                system("cls");
                break;
            case('x'):
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an [mcve] please

Comment: Could it be that there's a newline character that's still being read?

Comment: Don't use `gets`, this is dangerous function because it can overflow the buffer of the input is too large. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `case` is not a function, don't use it with parentheses like that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The code posted does not contain enough information to diagnose your problem. Please post an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a precise answer.

Note however that using `gets()` is a cause for potential buffer overflows, which has undefined behavior, a possible explanation for any unexpected results.

Use `fgets()` instead and pass the size of the destination array.

Comment: While this is certainly a good idea, it doesn't seem like it would be the solution to the problem unless he's typing at least 20 characters in response to the prompt.

Comment: @Barmar: indeed, I wrote *potential buffer overflows* and *a possible explanation*... MCVE is needed for an accurate diagnostic, but my suggestion seem to have helped the OP. As such, I don't think I deserve a downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, that was someone else (but I didn't upvote, either). I'm not sure why the OP accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is already answered, i realized there are quite a few things not professional with your code.

Starting with `char menu[] = "1 - run first task\n2 - run se...";`

Even though not giving size and initializing right away works in C, it is not a good practice, you should always either define a strict size, or dynamically allocate it (using malloc or calloc).

Secondly, you're using `gets()` to read from the console, which is a dangerous thing, and make your application vulnerable. `gets()` is considered dangerous due to its inability to deal with strings that are larger than size of buffer. And since you're taking user input, it's even worse, cause you should always consider the possibility that user might enter what they're not supposed to enter. **Never count on mercy of users.** Use `fgets` to read from either file or console, as you get to define how many maximum bytes you want to read at a time.

Thirdly, while using switch statement, along with the cases that you want to handle, always make a default case as well. Same thing, don't count on user. They may suppose to enter `'1'` but what if they enter `'9'`, if you have not handled that case, you might have some unexpected behavior from application.

Fourth, i see here your main objective is to let user decide menu option, instead of using a string, you can use a char, and instead of `gets()` or `fgets()`, you can use `getch()` or `getchar()`.

Below is little modified version of your code

```
int main(void)
{    
    char menu[200] = "1 - run first task\n2 - run se...";
    char x = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        puts(menu);
        x = getch();

        switch (x)
        {
        case ('1'):
            task1();
            break;

        case('2'):
            task2();
            break;

        case('c'):
            system("cls");
            break;

        case('x'):
            break;

        default:
            printf("Please choose a valid option!!");
            break;
       }
    }   
}
```

`

Comment: thx! See I've got that IF right before Switch supposed to validate input so I should be good with odds :) Besides getchar and stuff will be getting first chars of a string input and in this way making some strings valid for proceeding to char-Switch regardless of there length which is not always good.